# How to have a buildbot GitPoller change source watch all branches?

Tags: python, git, continuous-integration, buildbot

I'm looking for a way to have a GitPoller `changesource` watch all branches instead of just one.

For now, either I specify `branch='some branch'` in the GitPoller constructor, or it defaults to `master`.

Even better would be to be able to specify some `ref` pattern to watch.

Is that something one does already? Or does it need to code another kind of GitPoller ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is finally implemented: https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/pull/1010.

Should be part of the upcoming release of buildbot 0.8.9.

You can use `branches=True` then.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `GitPoller` can only watch a single branch at a time. However, you can have as many `GitPoller`s as you want.

Comment: The idea would be to have some kind of poller that can watch a variable number of git heads, so I cannot create one gitpoller per head. I will probably hack something around the current poller, I already need to make it support recursive submodules anyway.

Comment: I'd also like to see some way to watch all branches. In our system we want to build several developer branches and they come and go so adding them manually is a real issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed in the latest release of buildbot 8.8.8

https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/blob/master/master/buildbot/changes/gitpoller.py

Edit:

You can use `branches=[ 'development', 'other' ]` in place of `branch='development'`

Comment: Can you elaborate? No mention of "all branches" anywhere in the source code.

Comment: @g-allen-morris-iii: The op asked for a way to track *all* branches. However the change you mentioned only made it possible to track *multiple* branches.